# How to deserialize protobuf to custom object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, grpc

Im trying to figure out with gRPC.
I send stream data from grpc server to client.
greet.proto:

```
message protoTagValueDouble {
        int64 TagId = 1;
         google.protobuf.Timestamp DateTime = 2;
         google.protobuf.Timestamp DateTimeUtc = 3;
         google.protobuf.Timestamp TimeStampUtc = 4;
         int32 OpcQuality = 5;
         string Tagname = 6;
         double Value =7;
}

message Response {
    repeated protoTagValueDouble items = 1;
}
```

In my server and client services i have special class for this message:

**UPDATED TagValueDouble 15.02.24**

```
  [ProtoContract] 
    public class TagValueDouble
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public long TagId { get; set; }
    
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
    
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public DateTime? DateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public DateTime? TimeStampUtc { get; set; }
    
        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public int OpcQuality { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public string Tagname { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(7)]
        public double? Value { get; set; }
    }
```

So, in client, i want to receive stream message like a *repeated message Response*, and map it to the List *TagValueDouble*  by the most perfomance way- Serialize/Deserialize is the best way, isnt?

Now i use *New()* for every item mapping, and think thats not good, but it works.

Server:

```
    public override async Task Transfer(Request requestStream, IServerStreamWriter<Response> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
.................................
        while (!_storage.IsEmpty && !context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            List<protoTagValueDouble>? protoItems = new();
            foreach (var tagValueDouble in _storage.DequeueChunk(10000))
            {
                if (tagValueDouble==null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                protoItems.Add(new protoTagValueDouble()
                {
                    TagId = tagValueDouble.TagId,
                    DateTime = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp.FromDateTimeOffset(tagValueDouble.DateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue),
                    DateTimeUtc = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp.FromDateTimeOffset(tagValueDouble.DateTimeUtc ?? DateTime.MinValue),
                    TimeStampUtc = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp.FromDateTimeOffset(tagValueDouble.TimeStampUtc ?? DateTime.MinValue),
                    OpcQuality = tagValueDouble.OpcQuality,
                    Tagname = tagValueDouble.Tagname,
                    Value = tagValueDouble.Value??0.0
                });
            }

            protoResponse = new Response();
            protoResponse.Items.AddRange(protoItems);
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(protoResponse);
        }
    }
.................................
```

Client:

```
.................................
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && batchCounter<100000)
    {
        await foreach (var response in serverData.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            foreach (var protoItem in response.Items)
            {
                _storage.Enqueue(new TagValueDouble()
                {
                    TagId = protoItem.TagId,
                    DateTime = protoItem.DateTime.ToDateTime(),
                    DateTimeUtc = protoItem.DateTimeUtc.ToDateTime(),
                    TimeStampUtc = protoItem.TimeStampUtc.ToDateTime(),
                    OpcQuality = protoItem.OpcQuality,
                    Tagname = protoItem.Tagname,
                    Value = protoItem.Value 
                });
            }
        }
..................................
```

On another hand, i want to serialize the message stream on the server side, and deserialize on the client, right?
Client, something like this??:

```
        await foreach (var response in serverData.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            var bytes = response.ToByteArray();
            using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            {
                var x = Serializer.Deserialize<List<TagValueDouble>>(stream);
            }
        }
```

Server, i don't understand how to realize it. Or my idea is totally wrong???

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're using both Google.Protobuf and protobuf-net here; is that right? You can go direct to protobuf-net, if that's what you're trying to do - well, sort of: your example is a little nuanced, but: the datetime Vs timestamp problem is solved by "compatibility level": https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/compatibilitylevel ; the abstract / concrete thing: protobuf-net*does have* direct support for that via protoinclude, but that doesn't fix this exact data shape; honestly, if it was me I'd keep things simple and have the DTO match the model, i.e. one type not two...

Comment: ...perhaps using an interface if I need to allow some aspects to be shared between other types; but what is your priority here? Which library would you rather be using? And if you have two known types, the fastest way to get from one to the other (assuming non-blittable, like here) is simply `new`, not serialization

Comment: Hi, both Google.Protobuf and protobuf-net, becouse i cant choose right way, and dont understand how protobuf-net works.  What do you mean about "two known types"?,  i have data entity class TagValueDouble and i should declare proto message for it, can i use only TagValueDouble? My priority is data transfer/mapping speed, that's all. I'm trying to find a suitable implementation.

Comment: in other words, how can I use one type instead of two?

Comment: well, the absolute simplest way of using one type here would be, since you clearly already have the Google/protocol bits working: delete everything else and just use those; if you would prefer to use protobuf-net, I can help you get that working, but I wouldn't start with your abstract/concrete pair: that's not a good fit for this data

Comment: Sorry for delay, i want to figure out with protobuf-net, and compare it with Google.Protobuf.  I changed TagValueDouble from abstract to concrete.